# How to crop the image using the image package "image.copyCrop method" in aspect ratio 1/1

Tags: flutter, image, image-cropper

i'm asking the user to crop any image he choose from the gallery with the image cropper with aspect ratio 1/1 then i realize that image package can also crop without even asking the user but i don't know how to calculate the aspect ratio if it is 1/1 and how to pass these values to the image.copycrop(int x, int y, int height,int width) !

i was using this code to crop

```
 final croppedImage = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
            sourcePath: images!.path,
            cropStyle: CropStyle.rectangle,
            compressQuality: 100,
            compressFormat: ImageCompressFormat.jpg,
            aspectRatio: const CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 0.8, ratioY: 1.0),
```

now i figured out that i can crop with image package but i don't know how to insert the values like the cropasepectratio(0.8,1.0)

```
 var decodedImage = await decodeImageFromList(File(images!.path).readAsBytesSync());
          print(decodedImage.width);
          print(decodedImage.height);

          final imageBytes =
              decodeImage(File(images!.path).readAsBytesSync())!;

          img.Image cropOne = img.copyCrop(
            imageBytes,
            100,
            100,
            decodedImage.width,
            decodedImage.height,
          );
          File(images!.path).writeAsBytes(encodePng(cropOne));
```

Comment: You have share details like which package you have used also please post some code what you have done already?

Comment: @PratikButani done i posted soe code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution to crop and keep the aspect ratio of 1/1. It crops the image exactly in the middle.

```dart
var decodedImage = await decodeImageFromList(File(images!.path).readAsBytesSync());
print(decodedImage.width);
print(decodedImage.height);

var cropSize = min(decodedImage.width, decodedImage.height);
int offsetX = (decodedImage.width - min(decodedImage.width, decodedImage.height)) ~/ 2;
int offsetY = (decodedImage.height - min(decodedImage.width, decodedImage.height)) ~/ 2;

final imageBytes = decodeImage(File(images!.path).readAsBytesSync())!;

img.Image cropOne = img.copyCrop(
  imageBytes,
  offsetX,
  offsetY,
  cropSize,
  cropSize,
);
print(cropOne.height);
print(cropOne.width);

File(images!.path).writeAsBytes(encodePng(cropOne));
```